# List child items in columns for parent view

Tags: sql, firebird

I had a table with a structure like:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+
| id | chld1fld1 | chld1fld2 | ... | chld1fld5 | chld2fld1 | ... | chld6fld5 |
+----+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+-----------+-----+-----------+
```

I remodeled it to get a proper parent-child relationship. Thing is that, for compatibility reasons with legacy systems, I'd like to have a view that reproduced the old structure. I managed to do it with subqueries:

```
SELECT parent.id,
    (SELECT c.field1 FROM child c WHERE (c.parent_id = parent.id) AND (id = 1)) AS chld1fld1,
    (SELECT c.field2 FROM child c WHERE (c.parent_id = parent.id) AND (id = 1)) AS chld1fld2,
    ...
    (SELECT c.field5 FROM child c WHERE (c.parent_id = parent.id) AND (id = 6)) AS chld6fld5
FROM parent
```

But I'm worried about the number of fetches that are needed for this operation. So is there a better way to do this? Maybe if I could at least fetch all child fields in a single subquery, it would be a lot better already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    c1.field1 as chld1fld1,
    c1.field2 as chld1fld2,
    --etc
    c2.field1 as chld2fld1,
    c2.field2 as chld2fld2
    --etc
FROM parent p
JOIN child c1
    ON p.parent_id = c1.parent_id
    AND c1.id = 1
JOIN child c2
    ON p.parent_id = c2.parent_id
    AND c2.id = 2  -- Or whatever identifies this as the second child
-- Add more joins as necessary
```